# Unable to install Ubuntu (Lenovo Legion Y520)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi, ssd

I have a Lenovo Legion Y520 laptop with 256 GB SSD and 2 TB HDD and pre-installed Windows 10. I've tried installing Ubuntu in by making a partition in the HDD.

The pre-installed Windows 10 is UEFI based.

**Question 1:** I couldn't really figure out how to get into the boot-menu.
(I used Recovery/Advanced Startup/Start up from Device)

**Question 2:** Is there a problem if I install Ubuntu on my HDD instead of my SSD?

**Question 3:** While trying to install Ubuntu, I got an error message saying Ubuntu that the other OS is a BIOS mode and there's a risk of losing the other Operating System.

As my question indicates, I'm a beginner at this and I request that you try to answer in a detailed way. Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a paper-clip or eq to enter the boot menu, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jYqfeWh1MY

Comment: Your machine is UEFI capable, but Windows may be installed in legacy mode.  If the boot devce (SSD) does not have an EFI partition, and uses a  dos partition table, Windows is in legacy mode, and an Ubuntu install to the SSD should be in legacy mode.  Installling Ubuntu to the (non-booting) HDD may be made in either mode, If you choose UEFI, put an EFI partition on it.  Choose UEFI first in the BIOS before booting the install media.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Flash Ubuntu on a USB, with for example Rufus.
2. Disable secure boot and fast boot in BIOS which you can access by pressing F2 when the Lenovo logo appears at boot.
3. Enable UEFI instead of Legacy.
4. If you want to install Ubuntu and Windows on the same disk, create a partition in windows disk management to install Ubuntu on that.
5. If you want to install Ubuntu on a separate disk, just follow the Ubuntu installation and chose that disk in the installation, no, it won't wipe windows as Windows 10 is on a separate disk.